# What Parameter Types are allowed for overloaded != function in a class

Tags: c++, types, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

Just for learning purposes and if I would really like to compare apples with pies. And ignoring for the moment [rules and idioms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421708#4421708)

What type of parameter is allowed for overloaded operators, e.g. "operator !=" ?

Ok, it is expecting exactly one parameter, but what type?. Having read ['functions'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), ['declarations'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/declarations), ['types'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type) and ['operator overloading'](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), I still do not know it. Any restriction? Maybe the same as any other function? Can somebody confirm that?

Any help appreciated

Edit:

In my post I even linked the proposed dup. So, why mark it as dup. I read that thread before. My question is nowhere answered in the post. I am not sure how to rephrase the question. It is about the "C++ type" of the parameter in the overloaded operator function. A "C++ type" is something like described in [types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type). For example, I think that the type must be complete. Any other restrictions or requirements?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @πάν i'm not sur where the dup answers the question.

Comment: I have even a link in my question to the proposed duplicate. I read this. It does not answer my question. Therefore I have asked. @gsamaras, πάντα ῥεῖ . Maybe you ust read the header of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What type of parameter is allowed for overloaded operators, e.g. "operator !=" ?

There are very few restrictions, the most important being: you cannot overload operators for builtin types. So one of the two types for binary operators must be a user-defined type.

> #### [`[over.oper]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#6)
>
> An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or be a non-member function that has **at least one parameter whose type is a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an enumeration**. It is not possible to change the precedence, grouping, or number of operands of operators.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Good reference. That helped already, maybe not fully. Because it also works with pointers, for example with function pointers. Hm . . .

Comment: @Armin Could you give me an example? doesn't work for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6dc4a74caa36b4e.

Comment: Something like (very sorry for bad format):    "struct test{ bool operator != (bool(*)()) { return false; } };
    test t;
    bool checkSomething(){ return false; }
    bool testop(){ return( t!= checkSomething); }". Compiled with gcc8.2 -Wall- Wextra -pedantic on RPI 3B+

Comment: @Armin, "at least one of the parameters...". So yes, the other one can be anything, including a pointer. Your operator takes as first hidden parameter a reference to a class type (`test&`).

Answer (score 0):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison), the function signature (for a free function) is:

```
bool operator !=(const T &a, const T2 &b);
```

Where:

> T2 can be any type including T

Similar wording applies if `operator!=` is a class member function.  Plus what YSC said.

Comment: Thank you. Although, one could guess that the operand must be const and a reference. But also a int*** works. If we see T as int ***, then it is maybe a "const int *** &". It accepts also a int&&.